# Lost all the files after restart Linux14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, live-usb

How can I login the same account when start Linux, cause each time I shutdown the Linux(A liveUSB), all the documents were gone when restart again.

I want to set an account when each time I start the system I can login the Account which can store my files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LiveUSB does not save data. It is meant to test out and or recover data to an external hard-drive.

> **Your files are gone.**

Due note that some specific USB are able to save data made with a liveUSB, but that depends how you created that USB.

The Ubuntu Startup creator has an option, to reserve X amount of GB for storage purposes. To the best of my knowledge the Ubuntu Startup creator is the only one with this features. Feel free to correct me here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't reserve any storage for the LiveUSB, after adding some storage it can store files.@blade19899